# Identify type of dataFile while serializing/deserializing

Tags: c#, object, serialization, binary, formatting

I have a little problem. I want to deserialize a file from disk memory in c#. All is going very well! Actually, it even works! Except id like my code to be robust, so im testing what would happen if i loaded a datafile which is not compatible with the data i want to load.

The data i want to load is of type List. What im trying to load is a text file i plopped some numbers in and shaved the .txt extension off. However im getting an exception.

Exception:

```
Test method GuitarWorkshopTests.OrderAdministrationTests.Test_Load_NonAnimal_Class threw exception: 
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Het eind van de stroom is bereikt voordat parsering is voltooid.
```

Stack Trace:
__BinaryParser.Run()
ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
OrderAdministration.Load(String fileName) line 119
OrderAdministrationTests.Test_Load_NonAnimal_Class() line 198

I have fiddled around with fileStream.GetType() to validate that the object is of the right type but i have not been able to make it compile, im missing something. Below i will show the unit test and the function it uses. Thanks in advance! :D

unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Test_Load_NonAnimal_Class()
    {
        InjectorClass injector = new InjectorClass();   

        injector.Administration.Load(@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\x");

        Assert.AreEqual(true, injector.Administration.Orders.Count);
    }
```

The Load function:

```
public void Load(String fileName)
    {
        if (fileName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
        }
        String path = @Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\GuitarWorkshop\" + fileName;

        if (fileName.Contains(@"\"))
        {
            path = fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            String direc = @Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\GuitarWorkshop";
            if (!Directory.Exists(direc))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(direc);
            }
        }
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();
            if(fileStream.Length > 0)
            {
                Orders = format.Deserialize(fileStream) as List<Order>;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Binary formatter deserialize only works when Binary Formatter was used to serialize the data.  The Binary formatter adds types into the serialize data so the deserialize method will work.

Comment: BinaryFormatter won't deserialize broken binary data properly. The `fileStream.GetType()` is not about stream (file) type. It is about `fileStream` instance .Net type wich is `FileStream` for your sample.

Answer (score 1):

This:

> The data i want to load is of type List. What im trying to load is a text file i plopped some numbers in and shaved the .txt extension off.

And this:

> BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();

are not compatible. `BinaryFormatter` more or less writes binary data in a similar way it the data is represented in memory, it is absolutely not text-based, and I would not recommend using it.

There are a bunch of different ways to serialize data, either text based, or binary. It can either follow a defined generic format, like json or xml, or  a custom format.

If you just want to store a list of numbers, you might put one number on each line, read the file with `[File.ReadAllLines][2]` and parse each line with `double.TryParse` or `int.TryParse`

If you are serializing objects I would recommend using a format like Json with a [good library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to read/write the objects. This is probably the most common way to store data currently.

> I have fiddled around with fileStream.GetType() to validate that the object

This does not work. `GetType` returns the type of the fileStream, i.e. `FileStream`, not the type of the serialized object. The file itself would need to contain the type of the serialized data. Some serialization formats can do this in a standardized way, some prefix the file with a magic number that is unique to their particular file format.